# Using PHP 5.6 in OpenShift

Tags: php, openshift

I'm new to Git and OpenShift and I find it very difficult to use PHP 5.6 in OpenShift.

first, I was trying to setup my application with built-in php 5.4 of openshift, but I noticed I need version 5.6 or higher for it.

So.. I didnt some searching and found this: https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-diy-nginx-php

To get PHP 5.6 working at OpenShift, you have to do the following:

```
Create a new Openshift "Do-It-Yourself" application
Clone this repository
Add a new remote "openshift" (You can find the URL to your git repository on the Openshift application page)
Run git push --force "openshift" master:master
SSH into your gear
Wait for build to finish (This may take at least an hour)
Open http://appname-namespace.rhcloud.com/ to verify
```

But since I'm a total newb, I don't really get what I need to do.

- "Add a new remote "openshift" (You can find the URL to your git repository on the Openshift application page)"
  What does that mean? how do I do that?
- Run git push --force "openshift" master:master

Running it returned: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).` (Run via SSH)

Hope someone can help me with this. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

openshift is working in the basis of cartridges. There are many cartridges ready to deploy in openshift. But unfortunately there is no php5.4+ cartridges and there will not be a sudo command in a php5.4 cartridge so we can't update php. 
So you need a Do It Yourself Cartridge. 
You will have to download php 5.6 source code in to the DIY cartridge and compile & Install it yourself. Also you need a server say nginx.

**Here is the step by step way to get this done.**

- Log Into opeshift webconsole.
- Create a new application with DIY cartridge.
- Goto home directory in your computer, open your terminal and type 
  `git clone https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-diy-nginx-php.git`
- So that you will get a directory named **openshift-diy-nginx-php** in your home directory
- Then open your openshift web console. and click on your newly created application name.
- There you can see a field under source code at the right side of the screen .[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAlyJ.jpg)
- Thats your source code of the DIY cartridge. So you need to push the files we downloaded before to this location.
- So that you copy the url and goto the directory that we have downloaded and open terminel and type 
  `git remote add openshift ssh://url.git`
  (**don't forget to replace ssh://url.git with your source code url that we have copied**)
- Now you need to push the repository/directory to openshift. So that type this command in the same terminal `git push --force "openshift" master:master`
- after finishing the push the build process starts. Log into your application via ssh if needed. There is a good tutorial in openshift that teaches how to login to openshift via ssh.

**There you go with php 5.6 and NginX**

If you need any help. comment please

Comment: I finished the push, I don't get what I have to do now. my app currently returns errorr 503 service unavailable. I managed to connected my app with SSH but what is it for?

Comment: I think you need to restart your application via rhc/ssh, and you may need to start your nginx server. I don't know how nginx serves the files i did only apache. But after finishing the long build process you will get an nginx server with php5.6, so you need to push your code to the root directory of the nginx server via git. Sorry that i couldn't help you further. If my answer has cleared your question please accept/upvote it

Comment: After typing `git push --force "openshift" master:master` and waiting 1 hour for the process to finish, I get this error: `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To ssh://...@myurl.com/~/git/myapi.git/
 + a7c5c0c...5f6dddb master -> master (forced update)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://...@myapi-myurl.com/~/git/myapi.git/'`

Comment: That was clear in the error message during the build process the remote system was crashed/hanged. So that build process was not able to continue. You may need to redo all process again

Answer (score 0):

Try by running this on the terminal (YourApp is where is your DIY cartridge):

rhc cartridge add -a YourApp --env OPENSHIFT_PHP_VERSION=5.6.16 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-php